# Parsing og: tags with ColdFusion regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

If one wants to extract/match Open Graph (og:) tags from html, using regex (and ColdFusion 9+), how would one go about doing it?

And the tricky bit is that is has to cover both possible variations of tag formation as in the following examples:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
<meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
```

So far all I got is this:

```
<cfset tags = ReMatch('(og:)(.*?)>',html_content)>
```

It does match both of the links, however only the first type has the content bit returned with it. And content is something that I require.

Just to make it absolutely clear, the desired output should be an array with all of the OG tags (they could be 'type,image,author,description etc.). That means it should be flexible and not based on the og:type example alone.

Of course if it's possible, the ideal output would be a struct with the first column being the name of tag, and the second containing the value (content). But that can be achieved with the post processing and is not as important as extracting the tags themselves.

Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

So you want an array like ['og:author','og:type', 'og:image'...]?

Try using a regex like **og:([\w]+)**

That should give you a start.   You will have duplicates if you have two of the same og:foo meta tags.

You can look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) also to help parse the HTML for you.  It makes it a lot easier.

There are a few good blog posts on using it in CFML

[jQuery-like parsing in Java](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/4/6/jsoup-adds-jQuerylike-parsing-in-Java)

[Parsing, Traversing, And Mutating HTML With ColdFusion And jSoup](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm)

Comment: Hey, not exactly I'd like an array like ['<meta property="og:type" content="website" />','<meta property="og:description" content="this is a description of the website" /> '...]
Alternatively, it would be even better to have a struct like {'type':'website','description':'this is a description'...}
Thanks for the links, will check them out

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after the suggestion from @abbottmw (thank you very much!), here's the solution:

Download Jsoup jar file from here: http://jsoup.org/download

Then initiate it like this:

```
<cfhttp url="...." result="oghtml" > /*to get your html content*/
<cfscript>
    paths = expandPath("/lib/jsoup.jar"); //or wherever you decide to place the file
    loaderObj =createObject("component","javaloader.JavaLoader").init([expandPath('/lib/jsoup.jar')]);
    jsoup = loaderObj.create("org.jsoup.Jsoup");
    doc = jsoup.parse(oghtml);
    tags = doc.select("meta[property*=og:]"); 
</cfscript>
<cfloop index="e" array="#tags#">
    <cfoutput>
        #e.attr("property")# | #e.attr("content")#<br />
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

And that is it. The complete list of og tags is in the [tags] array.

Of course it's not the regex solutions, which was originally requested, but hey, it works!

Comment: "You do not need no stinkin' regex"! ;-) Seriously, nothing wrong with them, but as @abbottmw said, JSoup is a better tool for parsing html.